# How to stop Bash appending history

Tags: linux, bash

I am having a lot of trouble setting up the terminal history of Bash the way I want.

I would like to have no duplicate entries and if I enter a command I want it saved and the duplicates above removed.

The problem is the history command shows me it is functioning the way I want however once I log out the duplicates come back again. I believe it is just appending the history to the existing one.

I have these lines in my .bashrc file (~/.bashrc)

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
shopt -u histappend
```

I have even tried uncommenting shopt but it still appends the history on logout.

How can I have the history be exactly how it is before I logout?

Comment: Ah didn't know of it's existence, cheers.

Comment: Did you try `history -w`?     
It should write the history before logout.

Comment: @ztank1013 thanks that lead me in the right direction, I have now added the solution.

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer and accept that yourself, so the question will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .bash_logout file (`~/.bash_logout`) with the following content:

```
history -a
history -w
```

This writes the current history that is in memory to the .bash_history file and then removes duplicates before you logout.

Comment: Bash normally automatically saves the history. What's special about this sequence of history commands? And why does writing after appending make a difference?

Comment: @ChrisPage It's hard to explain in the limited text here but basically there are three histories. **session history** - everything newly entered in the session, **history file** - past history of everything before login and **current history** - what you see when you list the history (combination of the **history file** and **session history**).

Comment: @ChrisPage when you use **erasedups** it stops you having duplicates in the **session history** only. If for example you had the command **ls** in the **history file** and you used it in this session **current history** would only show one entry for the command **ls**. However by default Bash appends **session history** to the **history file** both of which contain the command **ls** so next time you log in there are 2 **ls** commands listed. If you use it again there will be 3 next time you log in.

Comment: @ChrisPage by running history -a really what it does is the same as the default save that Bash does however this is not why we use it here. We use it because it removes all duplicates in the **current history** so that **current history** is now exactly what we want the history to look like. we then use history -w to write the **current history** to the **history file**. Hope that all made sense. I know by looking at it is seems silly to use history -a when you are going to overwrite it again with history -w but the key is history -a changes the **current history**.

Comment: @Craig Thanks, that’s helpful, but is it actually necessary to `history -w`? Won’t bash save it automatically?

Comment: @ChrisPage Are you saying bash runs `history -w` after running the .bash_logout script? If so I did not know this, I assumed that nothing would be done except what is in the logout script.

Comment: @Craig bash saves the history by default for interactive shells, without a logout script.

Comment: @ChrisPage yes I know that but it does not save it the way I would like, hence using the logout script to achieve the result I desired. Your original question was why it makes a difference to write after appending and the answer is that appending removes duplicates in the current history (combined history file and session history) which you then write to the history file. Bash's default save still saves duplicates to the history file because it only ensures that there are no duplicates in the session history not the current history.

Answer (score 0):

@Danny Staple's answer is good, but doesn't work for me, once I logged out the duplicates come back again (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 BASH). But that give me a right direction to go. I fine tune it a little. Likewise, go editing the file `~/.bash_logout` as following:

```
history -w
history -c
```

Finally, history duplication won't bother me any more.